# Distribute objects evenly along a curved path in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is it possible to use a path generated like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eraa18ty/) to place objects?

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("basis");
```

The goal is to achieve an even distribution of objects along the path like this:

[image]

Comment: D3 doesn't provide anything to do that; you'd have to compute the positions of the circles yourself.

Comment: Thanks Lars.  This is sufficient for an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 doesn't provide anything to do that; you'd have to compute the positions of the circles yourself. You may find [this demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868) helpful for determining points along a path.

Comment: Actually the demo is precisely what I was looking for.  Thanks again!